# What is the fastest way to make 7000 api calls and transform the data with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have ~7000 api calls i need to make & transform then transform the data with Pandas (rename columns, merge dataframes, etc.)

I thought ayncio might work but i'm having trouble applying transformations on the returned dataframes because i need information carried over from looping through my list of calls.

```
the list of calls looks like:

list_of_calls = {"group1":[[url, {params dict}], [url2, {params dict}]],

                  "group2":[[url, {params dict}], [url2, {params dict}]]}
```

This works for creating the list of tasks but i'm not sure how to grab the `params dict` associated with each call to get the metadata for each dataframe that i need. These params inform the transformations i need to do to each dataset received from the API calls.

```
tasks = get_tasks(session)
responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

I'm not sure how to use the `gather.(*tasks)` while also grabbing the corresponding params dict

Looking for some general direction here, mainly whether or not a solution using ayncio is possible or something else.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to store your data into a class.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass
import aiohttp

@dataclass
class APICall:
    url: str
    params: dict[str, str]  # assuming a map of str to str
    data: dict | None

    async def update_data(self, session: aiohttp.ClientSession):
        """Get the data for this API call"""
        # needed some error handling
        async with session.get(self.url) as response:
            self.data = await response.json()
```

After that you are going to have all the data more structured into the dict. Every key points to a list of `APICall` instances with the attribute `data` set to `None`.

```py
dict_of_api_calls = {
    "group1": [APICall("some url", {"param": "value"})],
    "group2": [APICall("other url", {"param": "value"})]
}
```

Then can be used a function that receives the dict and makes all the API calls in an async way. This function is going to call the method `update_data` of every instance and is going to return when all the datas are updated.

```py
async def update_data(api_calls: dict[str, list[APICall]]):
    """Update the data for every APICall instance in the dict"""
    # missed some error handling here
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for list_of_calls in api_calls.values():
            for call in list_of_calls:
                tasks.append(call.update_data(session))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

So, at this point you have in your dict every `APICall` with his `url`, `params` and `data` associated.

**Why this code improves the process?**

- It is making use of concurrency. Due to network latency you are using the free CPU time to work in other task.
- The use of the same `aiohttp.ClientSession` instance avoids to establish the same connection twice to a server. No wasted time making handshakes.